# Emberjs nested route and resource

Tags: ember.js

This is a question that I'm not sure how to answer it, I have a nested route like this :

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('pages', function(){
        this.resource('page', { path: '/:id' }, function(){
            this.route('edit', function(){
                this.resource('images', function(){
                    this.resource('image', { path: '/:id'}, function(){
                        this.route('edit');
                    })
                }); 
            });
        });
    });
});
```

But the thing is that I don't know if my edit route (`this.route('edit', function(){})`) should be a `route` or a `resource`.

Because in my app, I will navigate like this :
(let's take the id 1 for pages and 2 for images)

`/pages/` => `/pages/1/` => `pages/1/edit` => `/pages/1/edit/images` => `/pages/1/edit/images/2`

But one problem is that when I setup the `{{link-to}}` like this :

page = this.modelFor('page');

```
{{#each item in model}}
    {{#link-to "image" page item}}
        {{list-row item=item}} //component to display row in a table
    {{/link-to}}
{{else}}
    {{no-items}} 
{{/each}}
```

My list of links looks like that :

```
/pages/1/edit/images/1
/pages/2/edit/images/2
/pages/3/edit/images/3
```

It's like the page id is using the same id as the image which I don't understand how that is possible :/

[edit] :

When I click on an image inside `/images/` it doing two transition and I have this in my console as debug :

```
      Rendering image with default view <webmob@view:default::ember844> Object {fullName: "view:image"}
vendor.js:28547 Could not find "image.index" template or view. Nothing will be rendered Object {fullName: "template:image.index"}
vendor.js:28547 Transitioned into 'pages.page.edit.images.image.index'
vendor.js:28547 Could not find "images.index" template or view. Nothing will be rendered Object {fullName: "template:images.index"}
vendor.js:28547 Transitioned into 'pages.page.edit.images.index'
```

[edit2]:

After I've created folder for my pages (I had the same warning for those route), it gives me this :

```
Could not find "pages" template or view. Nothing will be rendered Object {fullName: "template:pages"}
vendor.js:28547 Rendering pages.index with default view <webmob@view:default::ember518> Object {fullName: "view:pages.index"}
vendor.js:28547 Transitioned into 'pages.index'
```

[edit3]: This is the console output when my app structure is like this :

```
- templates/
-    pages.hbs
-    page.hbs
-    //other resources


 generated -> route:pages.index Object {fullName: "route:pages.index"}
webmob/routes/pages.js:12 DEBUG: Already log in
VM69786:161 Ember Inspector Active
vendor.js:28547 Rendering application with default view <webmob@view:toplevel::ember480> Object {fullName: "view:application"}
vendor.js:28547 Rendering pages with default view <webmob@view:default::ember489> Object {fullName: "view:pages"}
vendor.js:28547 generated -> controller:pages.index Object {fullName: "controller:pages.index"}
vendor.js:28547 Could not find "pages.index" template or view. Nothing will be rendered Object {fullName: "template:pages.index"}
vendor.js:28547 Transitioned into 'pages.index'
vendor.js:28547 generated -> route:page.index Object {fullName: "route:page.index"}
```

I have everything display fine, but always having the warning. When I create a pages folder like this :

```
- templates/
    -    pages/
        - index.hbs //empty file
    -    pages.hbs
    -    page.hbs
    -    //other resources
```

I have this in my console :

```
generated -> route:pages.index Object {fullName: "route:pages.index"}
webmob/routes/pages.js:12 DEBUG: Already log in
vendor.js:28547 Rendering application with default view <webmob@view:toplevel::ember419> Object {fullName: "view:application"}
vendor.js:28547 Rendering pages with default view <webmob@view:default::ember428> Object {fullName: "view:pages"}
vendor.js:28547 generated -> controller:pages.index Object {fullName: "controller:pages.index"}
vendor.js:28547 Rendering pages.index with default view <webmob@view:default::ember443> Object {fullName: "view:pages.index"}
vendor.js:28547 Transitioned into 'pages.index'
vendor.js:28547 generated -> route:page.index Object {fullName: "route:page.index"}
VM70411:161 Ember Inspector Active
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of my projects, I stumbled upon a similar issue. I just checked my source code:

```
// Routing map
App.Router.map( function() {
    this.resource('projects', function() {
        this.resource('project', {path: ':name'}, function() {
            this.resource('edit', function() {
                this.resource('type', {path: '/type/:type_name'});
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I can access and edit a type inside a project with: `/projects/MyNewProject/edit/type/RandomType` (since I use my types' names and not their ids).

I remember noticing the exact same behavior as you did: if I used `:name` in both `project`and `type`resources, the generated link would be something like `/projects/MyNewProject/type/MyNewProject`. So having the same `:id` parameter for both your `page` and `image` resources probably is the cause of the problem. You might try `:image_id`for your `image` resource, and stick with `:id` for your `page` resource.

As for the other aspect of your question, regarding whether you should use `route` or `resource` for your first `edit` route: the [Ember Routing guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/) suggests that "You should use this.resource for URLs that represent a noun, and this.route for URLs that represent adjectives or verbs modifying those nouns."

But it doesn't seem so straightforward in your example, since you have a "resource" route nested inside an "action" route. I think you should use a `resource`, since the endpoint of your route (an image) is a resource.

Comment: Oh my god ! that was so logical... many many thanks ! I also change my router into a `resource` too and it's working fine. But I have one last issue, it's when I click on an image the URL is not `/pages/2/edit/images/1` but still `/pages/2/edit/images`, I can see that its going to the good id, but it automatically redirect to the images/ do you know why ? (it does 2 transition...)

Comment: I don't really have an clue about this remaining issue. Have you tried instantiation your Ember app with LOG_TRANSITIONS and/or LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL flags? (see http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/debugging/)

Comment: I have the flags already, I have updated the main topic. Even when I fixe those warning, I still have the same problem.

Comment: From the output of your console, it seems that Ember cannot resolve some of your templates. Maybe it has to do with their naming, i.e. I think you need to have templates named "images/index" and "image/index". Are you using the Ember Inspector extension for Chrome or Firefox? In its "Routes" tab, you can inspect which is the current route, and which template is associated to this route.

Comment: I am using Ember inspector for Chrome. Also I am using ember-cli and the naming is kinda tricky because I need to create folders for nested route, but not always so I'm kinda lost.. I need to have /templates/images/index.hbs as my images template and same for image ?

Comment: Yes, you guessed it right, you need to have your file tree reflecting the template names, i.e. images/index.hbs and image/index.hbs. But the template name itself doesn't necessarily reflect all the url components nesting. This seems to be explained in-depth [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-resources).

Comment: I have placed my pages routes, controller and template into folder, and now it's telling me that it can't find the pages controller so it transition to pages.index. I guess ember is using one or the other ?

Comment: Could you please copy/paste the console output? Normally, an `App.PagesIndexController` should be associated with the `pages.index` route.

Comment: Sorry that it took me a while to reply. Do you still have the issue? From what I understand, when you are visiting your /pages URL, both your `PagesRoute` and `PagesIndexRoute` are active (along with the controllers `PagesController` and `PagesIndexController`).
When you select a page, you __still__ are under `PagesRoute`, but also under `PageIndexRoute` (singular).
This way, the template for the "outer" route (`PagesRoute`) is displayed in both cases, while the content injected into `{{outlet}}` of your `pages.hbs` template depends on the "inner" route (`PagesIndexRoute` or `PageIndexRoute`).

Comment: Ah yes I see, but I still have the same issue. I pulled my hair off yesterday trying to understand why it wasn't working and I think I'm going to do something else for my case because I'm really lost ^^. But thank you for the explaination, I didn't realised that the `PagesRoute` was still use even though it's obvious..

Comment: Yes, this routing stuff can be a bit tricky, and having a break should help :). Maybe if you could isolate a part of the code to make a JSFiddle, or if you have it on a GitHub repo, I could have a look.